# Apache Tomcat 7 displays blank page Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: java, macos, apache, tomcat

It seems like this must have been answered, but I just spent an hour going through old questions, some of which sound just like mine, but my issue isn't solvable by the methods given.

Basically, I've got a default installation of Apache Tomcat 7.0.50 and when I go to localhost:8080, all I get is a blank page. In fact, if I try to go anywhere on localhost:8080 (not just the default start page), I get a blank page. When I shut Tomcat down, `netstat -anf inet` shows nothing connected to port 8080, so only Tomcat is using that port.

catalina.2014-01-16.log contains the following at any point at which I tried to load a page:

```
Jan 16, 2014 1:28:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process SEVERE: Error processing request
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_ERROR
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:456)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

At the exact same time, localhost.2014-01.16.log contains this stack trace (which I shortened because you don't need the whole thing):

```
Jan 16, 2014 1:28:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception
[javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.parseMediaType(Ljava/io/StringReader;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/http/parser/MediaType;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.parseMediaType(Ljava/io/StringReader;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/http/parser/MediaType;
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.MediaTypeCache.parse(MediaTypeCache.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.setContentType(Response.java:805)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setContentType(ResponseFacade.java:245)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:51)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at ...
```

I note it's a `NoSuchMethodError`. It seems like I must have a strange mix of libraries, but it's a default installation. I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. It turned out that someone had copied some other libraries into the Tomcat lib directory and I didn't realize it when upgrading. These other libraries are not compatible with Tomcat 7. Removing the offending jars fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

- What version of jdk did you use to run tomcat? Was it OpenJDK, Oracle JDK? Try running tomcat using Oracle JDK 1.6 or 1.7
- What OSX user did you use to run tomcat? Have you made sure it has all sufficient permission to read/write files into the directory?

Comment: I'm running Oracle JDK 1.7. I'm running Tomcat as myself, I have administrator permissions. Just now I tried `sudo ./startup.sh`. As usual, it starts just fine, but will only display a blank page.

Edit: I used to have a working installation of Tomcat 6, so I know I can run Tomcat on my system.